# Is there a way to GROUP BY using one column, but a set of values it could equal for a given group?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Is there a way to GROUP BY using one column, but a set of values it could equal for a given group?

For instance, say I have the records:

```
id = 1, quantity = 40, type = 1
id = 2, quantity = 50, type = 2
id = 3, quantity = 20, type = 1
id = 4, quantity = 30, type = 3
id = 5, quantity = 60, type = 3
```

And I would like to group types 1 and 2 together, and group type 3s by themselves. Is there a simple way to do this in MySQL, or am I better off doing this after I get the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create a custom group using a CASE statement:

```
  select case when id in (1,2) 
              then '1,2' 
              else id 
              end as custom_id_group
         ...
group by case when id in (1,2) 
              then '1,2' 
              else id 
              end
```

---

Edit:
Using the result of a CASE statement, via alias, in the GROUP BY clause isn't universally supported across RDBMSs, but more-recent versions of MySQL (>=5) will support it.

Comment: Perfect. Is it possible to use the CASEd column 'custom_id_group' in my GROUP BY clause, or do I have to repeat the CASE twice as above?

Comment: More-recent versions of MySQL definitely support using an alias. Not sure about earlier versions. Will update answer to include information about this. Since it is sometimes common to work with several RDBMSs I would use the most system-agnostic code possible, but that may not be a concern in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use two query and union the result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use something like "select *, if (type=1 or type=2, 'bigtype', type) as group_by_clause group by group_by_clause.
I didn't try it

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
select count(*), if(type in (1, 2), 12, type) t from table group by t
```